# Is libGDX suited for desktop-only application development?

Tags: desktop-application, game-engine, libgdx

I'm currently a few months into teaching myself java via books and online tutorials. Steep learning curve. Since I do that in my sparse free time, I have little hope of getting really good with every aspect of the language anytime soon. I have created simple programs that use lwjgl for the graphics.

I am looking for a framework/library that will help me with as much of the technical under-the-hood stuff as possible. I'd rather concentrate on writing a game than becoming an OpenGL genius or inventing a GUI from the ground up when there are libraries "out there" that do it better than I ever could. I simply can't invest the time needed, but would still love to write a game of my own.

Would you recommend libGDX for that purpose, considering I only want to write desktop-only applications? Or is it more of an Android-API which also happens to run on Desktop (for debugging?). Are there alternatives better suited for desktop applications?

I really like what I've read about libGDX until now, it seems to provide useful tools for every aspect of game-development. I just don't want to invest months in learning about it only to find that library XY would have been even better when it comes to desktop applications.

Thanks for your input, any help is appreciated!

Jan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would recommend libgdx for that purpose, for the following reasons:

- It provides a large number of wrappers for libraries such as Box2D,
  OpenGL ES and FreeType, either in the core libraries or via extensions.
- It contains many [features](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/features.html) that you might otherwise need to implement, such as texture atlases, meshes, tiled maps, JSON serialisation, etc.
- It is non-opinionated, ie, you can pick and choose which parts you use and aren't forced into a "libgdx way" of doing things.
- It is actively developed and has a strong, helpful, [knowledgeable community](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/) around
  it.
- It is very portable across platforms, so what you develop on Windows will work on Mac and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. This confirms what I had hoped. I will try and give libGDX a go. Wish me luck, and thanks again for the info!